# image not linking to user during migration

Tags: migrations

I run a migration to first import images as below , it works and imports the pictures as files but when i do the user import with the snipped at the end of this post it doesnt attach the image to the user

```
id: vcd7_user_pictures
label: 'user pictures migration'
migration_group: custom
source:
  constants:
    DRUPAL_FILE_DIRECTORY: 'public://profiles/'
  plugin: vcd7_user_pictures
 
  ids:
    photo_id:
      type: string
process:
  psf_destination_filename:
    plugin: callback
    callable: basename
    source: photo_url
  psf_destination_full_path:
    - plugin: concat
      source:
        - constants/DRUPAL_FILE_DIRECTORY
        - '@psf_destination_filename'
    - plugin: urlencode
  psf_source_image_path:
    plugin: urlencode
    source: photo_url
  uri:
    plugin: file_copy
    source:
      - '@psf_source_image_path'
      - '@psf_destination_full_path'
    file_exists: 'rename'
    move: FALSE
    uid: uid
   
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
migration_dependencies: {}  `
```

this is the code in my user migration

```
user_picture: # Image field name in Drupal 8 site
-
  plugin: default_value
  source: user_picture # Image field name in Drupal 7 site
  default_value: null
-
  plugin: migration_lookup
  migration: vcd7_user_pictures
```

Comment: Indentation is wrong in user migration. Is it copy paste error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My plugin was using user information instead of file information .  instead i changed to the generic plugin for files
source:
plugin: d7_file

and it worked .